# Application become Scrollable with Worklight on iOS7

Tags: ios, ibm-mobilefirst, dojo, worklight-studio

I have developed one sample application with Worklight 6.0.0.1 on Eclipse and deployed the application on iPhone(iOS7 device). Following is the code for my first view.

```
        <body id="content" style="display: none;">

        <div data-dojo-type="dojox.mobile.View" id="view0" data-dojo-props='selected:true'>
            <h1 data-dojo-type="dojox.mobile.Heading" data-dojo-props='fixed:"top"'>Application Header Bar</h1>
            <div id="view1" data-dojo-type="dojox.mobile.ScrollableView">

            </div>
            <h1 data-dojo-type="dojox.mobile.Heading" data-dojo-props='fixed:"bottom"'>Application Footer Bar</h1>

        </div>
        <script src="js/initOptions.js"></script>
        <script src="js/TestApp.js"></script>
        <script src="js/messages.js"></script>
    </body>
```

When i tested it on device/simulator, i found out that i can move even the footer above. Please see snapshots for more detail.

[image]
[image]

I have taken **data-dojo-type="dojox.mobile.View"** for my View Even then its getting scroll above don't know how. Anybody having any idea.

regards,
V@run

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think what you are describing is the UIWebView "bounce", or "rubber-band" or "overscroll". It's not specific to Worklight but rather is a "feature" of everything built with a UIWebView.

One quick way to disable this is to open the config.xml of your iOS Worklight project. Those are settings specific to the Cordova UIWebView.

Add this preference:

```
<preference name="DisallowOverscroll" value="true" />
```

Let me know if this fixed your problem.